# Concurrently process a lot of files and upload to S3 in Go

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I'm migrating a lot of files that are currently stored in a relational database to amazon S3. I'm using go because I had heard about the concurrency of it, but I'm getting very low throughput. I'm new to go so I'm probably not doing it in the best way possible.

This is what I have at the moment

```
type Attachment struct {
    BinaryData []byte `db:"BinaryData"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `db:"CreatedDT"`
    Id int `db:"Id"`
}

func main() {
    connString := os.Getenv("CONNECTION_STRING")

    log.SetFlags(log.Ltime)
    db, err := sqlx.Connect("sqlserver", connString)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Print("Connected to database")

    sql := "SELECT TOP 1000 Id,CreatedDT, BinaryData FROM Attachment"

    attachmentsDb := []Attachment{}
    err = db.Select(&attachmentsDb, sql)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    session, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("eu-west-1"),
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    svc := s3.New(session)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for _, att := range attachmentsDb {

        done := make(chan error)
        go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, att Attachment, out chan error) {
            wg.Add(1)
            err := <-saveAttachment(&att, svc)
            if err == nil {
                log.Printf("CV Written %d", att.Id)
            }
            wg.Done()
            out<-err
        }(wg, att, done)
        <-done
    }
    wg.Wait()
    //close(in)
    defer db.Close()
}

func saveAttachment(att *Attachment, svc *s3.S3 )<-chan error {
    out := make(chan error)

    bucket := os.Getenv("BUCKET")

    go func() {
        defer close(out)


        key := getKey(att)
        input := &s3.PutObjectInput{Bucket: &bucket,
            Key:  &key,
            Body: bytes.NewReader(att.BinaryData),
        }
        _, err := svc.PutObject(input)
        if err != nil {
            //log.Fatal(err)
            log.Printf("Error uploading CV %d error %v", att.Id, err)
        }
        out <- err


    }()
    return out
}

func getKey(att *Attachment) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s/%d", os.Getenv("KEY"), att.Id)
}
```

Comment: You are processing sequentially. The read from done channel in the for loop will wait for the goroutine to complete. Move it out of the for loop. That'll leave you with many concurrent uploads, and you might want to limit them. And you are ignoring the returned error values. You might want to return a status giving you what is uploaded and if it was successful, so when everything is said and done you can have a list of failed uploads.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can the limit be done with a buffered channel?

Comment: One way to do it is you create n goroutines, n being the limit, each reading the item to be uploaded from the same channel and doing the upload until channel is closed. And then you simply write to the channel and close it when everything is written. There is no need for a buffered channel.

Answer (score 2):

These loops will executes sequentially because in every loop, it waits for result from channel `done` so there aren't any benifit from running multiple goroutines. And no need to create a new goroutine in `func saveAttachment()`, because you already create it in the loops.

```
func main() {
    //....
    svc := s3.New(session)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for _, att := range attachmentsDb {
        done := make(chan error)
        //New goroutine
        go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, att Attachment, out chan error) {
            wg.Add(1)
            //Already in a goroutine now, but in func saveAttachment() will create a new goroutine?
            err := <-saveAttachment(&att, svc) //There is a goroutine created in this func
            if err == nil {
                log.Printf("CV Written %d", att.Id)
            }
            wg.Done()
            out<-err
        }(wg, att, done)
        <-done //This will block until receives the result, after that a new loop countinues  
    }
}

func saveAttachment(att *Attachment, svc *s3.S3 )<-chan error {
    out := make(chan error)

    bucket := os.Getenv("BUCKET")

    //Why new goroutine?
    go func() {
        defer close(out)

        key := getKey(att)
        input := &s3.PutObjectInput{Bucket: &bucket,
            Key:  &key,
            Body: bytes.NewReader(att.BinaryData),
        }
        _, err := svc.PutObject(input)
        if err != nil {
            //log.Fatal(err)
            log.Printf("Error uploading CV %d error %v", att.Id, err)
        }
        out <- err

    }()
    return out
}
```

If you want to upload in parallel, don't do that. You can quickly fix it like this

```
func main() {
    //....
    svc := s3.New(session)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    //Number of goroutines = number of attachments 
    for _, att := range attachmentsDb {
        wg.Add(1)
        //One goroutine to uploads for each Attachment
        go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, att Attachment) {
            err := saveAtt(&att, svc)
            if err == nil {
                log.Printf("CV Written %d", att.Id)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(wg, att)
        //No blocking after created a goroutine, loops countines to create new goroutine
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("done")
}

//This func will be executed in goroutine, so no need to create a goroutine inside it
func saveAtt(att *Attachment, svc *s3.S3) error {
     bucket := os.Getenv("BUCKET")
     key := getKey(att)
     input := &s3.PutObjectInput{Bucket: &bucket,
         Key:  &key,
         Body: bytes.NewReader(att.BinaryData),
     }
     _, err := svc.PutObject(input)
     if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error uploading CV %d error %v", att.Id, err)
     }
     return err
}
```

But this approach isn't good when there are so many attachments beacause number of goroutines = number of attachments. In this case, you will need a goroutine pool so you can limit number of goroutines to run.

Warining!!!, This is just an example to show goroutine pool logic, you need to implement it by your way

```
//....

//Create a attachment queue
queue := make(chan *Attachment) //Or use buffered channel: queue := make(chan *Attachment, bufferedSize)
//Send all attachment to queue
go func() {
    for _, att := range attachmentsDb {
        queue <- &att
    }
}()
    
//....

//Create a goroutine pool

svc := s3.New(session)
wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    
//Use this as const
workerCount := 5
//Number of goroutines = Number of workerCount
for i := 1; i <= workerCount; i++ {
    //New goroutine
    go func() {
        //Get attachment from queue to upload. When the queue channel is empty, this code will blocks
        for att := range queue {
            err := saveAtt(att, svc)
            if err == nil {
                log.Printf("CV Written %d", att.Id)
            }
        }
    }()
}

//....
  
//Warning!!! You need to call close channel only WHEN all attachments was uploaded, this code just show how you can end the goroutine pool  
//Just close queue channel when all attachments was uploaded, all upload goroutines will end (because of `att := range queue`)
close(queue)
//....
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no race condition in your last example: `queue <- &att` is run concurrently to the `close(queue)`. And I don't easily see what would prevent `close` to happen first sometimes.

Comment: It's just an example to show goroutine poll logic. Probably shouldn't call close channel like that, thanks for mentions me @zerkms

Comment: How to return error in this case ?